# Problem: failed to create task or type stopwatch Cause: The name is undefined

Tags: ant

> BUILD FAILED
>
> E:\Tasks\Task - 2 (ant dd)\Testing\build.xml:50: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> E:\Tasks\Task - 2 (ant dd)\Testing\checks.xml:123: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> E:\Tasks\Task - 2 (ant dd)\Testing\accountsurlcheck.xml:21: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> E:\Tasks\Task - 2 (ant dd)\Testing\accountsurlcheck.xml:54: Problem: failed to create task or type stopwatch
>
> Cause: The name is undefined.
>
> Action: Check the spelling.
>
> Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
>
> Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

Im getting this eror when I run ant .
I have copied ant-contrib-0.5.jar to the lib of ant installed directory and also added `<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>` to my `build.xml`.

line 54 of accountsurlcheck.xml :

```
<stopwatch name="total_time" action="start"/>
```

Line 21 :

```
<antcall target="urllist"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `taskdef` for ant-contrib is missing a classpath that points to the ant-contrib jar.

```
<taskdef
    classpath="/path/to/ant-contrib.jar"
    resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"
/>
```